# Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any' Called from: as.vector(by)

Tags: r, merge

I'm trying to create functions to merge data on NVDA's correlated ETF, but I'm having trouble understanding the error message:

Error in as.vector(x, mode) :
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
Called from: as.vector(by)

```
library(tidyverse)

D_NVDY_Pull <- function() {
  NVDY1 <- as.data.frame(read_csv("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/NVDY?period1=1683811800&period2=1709314910&interval=1d&events=dividends&includeAdjustedClose=true"))
  NVDY2 <- as.data.frame(read_csv("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/NVDY?period1=1683811800&period2=1709256228&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"))
  NVDY3 <- merge(NVDY1,NVDY2, by = `Date`)
    return(NVDY3)
```

I was trying to merge the data by NVDY2's `Date`. I'm not sure if I have to use select() or filter() first, but even then I'm not sure how that'd go because data will be added monthly. I can sort through the data afterwards, my end goal is to just have `Date`, `Closing` (or `adj Close`), and `Dividend` in the same data.frame().

Comment: What do you mean by *I was trying to merge the data by NVDY2's Date.* The merging should be performed on? They only share nine `Dates`.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, just change to:

```r
NVDY1 <- read.csv("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/NVDY?period1=1683811800&period2=1709314910&interval=1d&events=dividends&includeAdjustedClose=true")
NVDY2 <- read.csv("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/NVDY?period1=1683811800&period2=1709256228&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true")
NVDY3 = merge(NVDY1, NVDY2, by = "Date")
```

Without expected result chances are you want something different.

```
> NVDY3[c("Date", "Dividends", "Close", "Adj.Close")]
        Date Dividends  Close Adj.Close
1 2023-06-07     0.746 22.168  16.75575
2 2023-07-07     0.957 22.970  18.09345
3 2023-08-04     0.814 22.190  18.12354
4 2023-09-08     0.930 22.650  19.24987
5 2023-10-06     0.677 22.050  19.32050
6 2023-11-08     0.415 21.290  19.01949
7 2023-12-07     0.507 21.100  19.31226
8 2024-01-05     0.626 21.870  20.60109
9 2024-02-07     1.530 25.310  25.31000
```

As you see, nine `Date`s remain.

Comment: You are my hero, thank you